# z index multiple elements

Tags: css, sass

hey guys I have 3 elements I'm using z-index and position property.
the first one is the main navbar (working fine)
the 2nd is sidenav
the 3rd is a button.

the button must have the position relative.
**when I'm scrolling the main navbar is taking over the button which is great !**
**but the side navbar is not.**
I did try to change the z-index on each element.

the mobile navbar is the main navbar which working fine.

```
.mobile-navbar {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;

  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  img {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.274);
  }
  div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    a {
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 5px;
      text-decoration: none;
      span {
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 0 3px;
      }
    }
  }
}

.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: 300ms ease-out;
  &-active {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(12, 6, 39);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: 300ms ease-out;
    button.close-nav {
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: rgb(14, 12, 12);
      color: #fff;
      border: none;
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    .dynamic-links {
      height: 30%;

      button {
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 2rem;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
      }
      .sidenav-link {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 0 10px;
      }
    }
    .sidenav-links {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 50%;
      .sidnav-link {
        color: #fff;
        margin: 10px 0;
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the button I need to use position relative and taking over the side-navbar:

```
 button {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border: none;
      outline: #06a821;
      border-radius: 30px;
      color: #fff;
      letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
      background: linear-gradient(
        90deg, 
        rgba(5, 116, 197, 1) 35%,
        rgba(106, 183, 239, 1) 100%
      );

      transition: ease-in-out 300ms;
      &::before {
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        left: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        top: 5px;
        bottom: 5px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        content: "";
      }
```

Comment: You haven't specified how your HTML looks like, i. e. what is the layout of the elements in the DOM tree (whether they are all on the same level or nested somehow).

Answer (score 0):

only had to add the z-index in the active class.
befor :

```
.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: 300ms ease-out;
  &-active {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(12, 6, 39);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: 300ms ease-out
```

after:

```
.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: 300ms ease-out;
  &-active {
    position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(12, 6, 39);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: 300ms ease-out;
```